# Show google play purchase menu on button Click

Tags: android, billing

I have a wallpaper project and i intend to check if user has an active subscription and then let him download wallpaper else show purchase menu too buy a new subscription. I decided to implement the BillingClient class in the event handler of the download button. I do now have any idea on how to combine `BillingClient` and `SkuDetails`to make it show the purchases menu. Here is waht i have tried so far. I just need good logic that i will implement in the button method to show the google play check out popout.
Here is my code

```
//My class implements the purchasesupdatedlistener
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements PurchasesUpdatedListener{
 //SUBSCRIPTION IS SET TO FALSE BY DEFAULT
  public boolean hasSubscription=false;
//This method handles the onclick of the button so i implemented BillingClient in the download button which has id R.id.cv_download
 @OnClick({R.id.edtSearch, R.id.cv_Share, R.id.cv_like, R.id.cv_download,R.id.ivRandom})
    public void onViewClicked(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.cv_download:
                //This is where the app's business logic goes
                //create a new BillingClient class
                 final BillingClient myclient= BillingClient.newBuilder(getActivity()).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();

                 //Establish connection to google play
                 myclient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                         //The building client is ready you can setup purchases here
                         switch(billingResult.getResponseCode()){
                             case OK:
                                 //Check if user has made a purchase for a subscription
                                 if(hasSubscription){
                                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"User has active subscription",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                     anImage      = ((BitmapDrawable) ivRandom.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                                     saveImageToExternalStorage(anImage);
                                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Download successfuly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 }else{
   //User has no active subscription so request him to buy a new one
  //This is where i am completely messed up
                                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"User has no active subscription",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                     //So launch billingresult flow
                                     try{
                                         final SkuDetails mydetails=new SkuDetails(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
                                         myclient.querySkuDetailsAsync(    SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder().build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                                             @Override
                                             public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> list) {
                                                 list.add(mydetails);

                                             }
                                         });
                                     }catch(JSONException k){
                                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),k.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                     }


                                 }


                         }

                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                    //Inform user that its not working and he should try some other time
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Connection Problems, Try Again Later",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                 });
                 //Implement conditional structure to check if user has subscription and then let him download



                break;
    }
//The billingClient interface is here
  @Override
        public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> list) {
         //To be implemented in a later section
         switch(billingResult.getResponseCode()){
             case OK:
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Payment made with success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              break;
             case ITEM_UNAVAILABLE:
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"This item is not available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 break;
             case ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED:
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You already own this item",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 break;
             case BILLING_UNAVAILABLE:
             case DEVELOPER_ERROR:
             case ERROR:
             case FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
             case ITEM_NOT_OWNED:
             case SERVICE_DISCONNECTED:
             case SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE:
                 default:
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Some other problem occurred",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     break;
         }
    }

}
```

I don't know how to create SkuDetails and show the buy popup menu, please help